# JSON, separating objects

Tags: php, json, api

My question is merely what is the best practice for this. Let's say I have an object like so:

```
{"player":[
    {
        "player_id": "1",
        "player_teams": [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "team_name": "Test Team",
                "team_link": "test-team",
            },
            {
                "id": "65",
                "team_name": "Test Team 2",
                "team_link": "test-test",
            }
        ]
        "player_leagues": [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "league_name": "Test League",
                "league_link": "test-league",
            },
            {
                "id": "65",
                "league_name": "Test League 2",
                "league_link": "test-league-2",
            }
        ]
    }
]}
```

Now obviously in the JSON file there are a few mysqli queries to get this info. Is it best to separate teams and leagues into two files? There are 5 sections that I would have to place in in the end. Basically people will be loading the JSON file and querying info that they aren't seeing on that page.

Did I answer my own question? lol

Thanks guys!

Comment: How about execute the query to get the info that they want and then send the JSON?  What is it with files?

Comment: true I could put it in one file and set a variable in the JSON url, then use GET to tell what section it is... good thinking

Comment: Is that the right way to do it?

Comment: I would wonder why you are using files?  Does the data never change?  The user does `?q=player_teams` and you just run that SQL query and return what is needed as JSON.

Comment: It's a JSON file that spits out the info... That is all.

Comment: OK, I don't know then, I just read _there are a few mysqli queries to get this info_.

Comment: In the JSON file there are queries turn it into json.